# PyDev and Django: Autocomplete not detecting Django?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, ide, pydev

I'm using PyDev with Django. The autocomplete works nicely in the shell - I start typing, and it suggests completions. However, this doesn't work in the main code editor window. How can I fix this?

I'm using:

Eclipse build #20100218-1602

PyDev 1.5.6

Eclipse IDE for Java Devs 1.2.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might need to set the editor code completion settings. They are under:

`Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Completion`

You might also need to add the Django install or your Django project to your path. You can set this under:

`Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Python`

Hope this helps.

Comment: To add Django to my python path, do I need to add a library under the Libraries tab? Which file would I add? `import django` already works on the command line.

Comment: I added `path\to\Django\Django-1.1.1\django` and it seemed to work pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to
Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters–>Python Interpreter

From Libraries (System PYTHONPATH),

1. make sure ..lib/site-packages is listed.
2. Remove any mention of lib/site-packages/Django