# Django autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I want to use the autocomplete of PyDev with Django in Eclipse. I've followed these two threads

[Autocompletion in Django + pydev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740847/autocompletion-in-django-pydev)

[PyDev and Django: Autocomplete not detecting Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815094/pydev-and-django-autocomplete-not-detecting-django)

so I went to

Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter

selected the libraries tab and added path\to\Django\Django-1.6.1\django

and then right-clicked on Project's name then Preferences -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH

clicked on the external libraries and added the project folder and

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

finally I went to

Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Completion

and checked that the autocomplete was on and it was so. But still don't have the auto-complete on. But it doesn't even autocomplete the variables that I have defined in the same class. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself. The problem wasn't related to PYTHONPATH or anything like that I had said above. The problem was with Aptana! I also noticed that Aptana that is now available for Windows x86 was 3.4.2 rather than 3.5 that was installed before. I think they had noticed that there are bugs in 3.5 and are now providing the 3.4.2 version.

**To fix this simply reinstall Aptana.**

Note: if you are getting "Port not bound (found port -1). Is there an enabled firewall?" after you enter some text and try [Ctrl + Space] you likely have the same problem.

Hope that helps for you.

Comment: Note that PyDev itself has improved a lot in the latest release (3.3.3 was a big leap compared to older versions), so, if Python is your main language it might be worth using pure Eclipse+PyDev or LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ to get the latest version (as Aptana usually lags behind in getting PyDev updated).